# "random" order clause added to my collection

Tags: magento-1, product-collection, sql, sorting, select

For a module I load a custom product collection where I select products based on IDs in an array, I also try and sort the collection by the same order as the IDs have in the array().

To achieve the sorting I use Zend's `getSelect->order()` to add a custom "ORDER BY" to the SQL statement.

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
            ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
            ->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', $productIds)
            ->addOrder('entity_id');

$sortIds = array_map('intval', $productIds);
$collection->getSelect()
           ->order("find_in_set(e.entity_id,'".implode(',', $sortIds)."')");
```

This will generate a SQL error: **"SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'cat_index_position' in 'order clause'"**, since I don't have the "cat_index_position" in my product flat table.

This error is because **Magento adds an extra ORDER BY clause**: `'cat_index_position' ASC` after the one I add with `getSelect()->order()`

If I don't add the `getSelect()->order()` no extra ORDER BY is added and no SQL error is generated, however the sort order is obviously wrong.

I can, very ugly, hack this by commenting out the rest of the SQL statement like this `$collection->getSelect()->order("find_in_set(e.entity_id,'".implode(',',$ids)."');--");` but I really really don't want to do that.

I need help tracking down the source of that extra ORDER BY clause or any other way of solving it.

**UPDATE**

If I do `$collection->getSelect()->__toString()` after I've added my custom order I get:

> SELECT 1 AS status, e.entity_id, e.type_id, e.attribute_set_id
>   FROM catalog_product_flat_1 AS e
>   WHERE (((e.entity_id = '8534') OR (e.entity_id = '4184') OR (e.entity_id = '4185') OR (e.entity_id =
>   '4183') OR (e.entity_id = '13314') OR (e.entity_id = '5069') OR
>   (e.entity_id = '11217') OR (e.entity_id = '4355') OR (e.entity_id =
>   '4354') OR (e.entity_id = '4353') OR (e.entity_id = '4352') OR
>   (e.entity_id = '4351') OR (e.entity_id = '4350') OR (e.entity_id =
>   '4349') OR (e.entity_id = '4348') OR (e.entity_id = '5203'))) ORDER BY
>   find_in_set(e.entity_id,'8534,4184,4185,4183,13314,5069,11217,4355,4354,4353,4352,4351,4350,4349,4348,5203')
>   ASC

And as I said previously, now Magento adds an extra ORDER BY, because the error I get say I have this SQL statement:

> SELECT 1 AS status, e.entity_id, e.type_id, e.attribute_set_id
>   FROM catalog_product_flat_1 AS e
>   WHERE (((e.entity_id = '8534') OR (e.entity_id = '4184') OR (e.entity_id = '4185') OR (e.entity_id =
>   '4183') OR (e.entity_id = '13314') OR (e.entity_id = '5069') OR
>   (e.entity_id = '11217') OR (e.entity_id = '4355') OR (e.entity_id =
>   '4354') OR (e.entity_id = '4353') OR (e.entity_id = '4352') OR
>   (e.entity_id = '4351') OR (e.entity_id = '4350') OR (e.entity_id =
>   '4349') OR (e.entity_id = '4348') OR (e.entity_id = '5203'))) ORDER BY
>   find_in_set(e.entity_id,'8534,4184,4185,4183,13314,5069,11217,4355,4354,4353,4352,4351,4350,4349,4348,5203')
>   ASC, cat_index_position ASC, e.entity_id ASC LIMIT 16

Comment: I think you need to add `addAttributeToSelect('cat_index_position')`, I believe it is obtained by a JOIN when building the collection and is not retrieved automatically.

Comment: This does not work, and shouldn't be needed since I have `addAttributeToSelect('*')`. Looking at the SQL statement after adding `addAttributeToSelect('cat_index_position')` doesn't add any extra JOINs.

Comment: Alright, do you mind updating the question with the whole SQL Query pls (just echo `(string)$collection->getSelect()` )?

Comment: @JulienLachal yes, I've added that information to the main question.

Comment: Check if there is any observer hooking into product collection before load adding this order. This is definitely not standard behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue with a module and the way I fixed it was setting the visibility as below. Just add the rest of your collection parameters after "setVisibility".

```
$products = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
    ->setVisibility(Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')->getVisibleInCatalogIds())
```

Answer (score 1):

What you can do to remove that statement automatically added is **manipulate the select object directly.**

So first write your first part of code:

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
        ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
        ->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', $productIds)
        ->addOrder('entity_id');
```

This code should not trigger any order.

Now you can **get the order part of the select object and remove the part you don't want**:

```
// Get the order part
$order = $collection->getSelect()->getPart('order');

// Loop through the order parts
foreach ($order as $key => $value) {
    // Remove if the unwanted key is found
    if ($key == "cat_index_position") {
        unset($order[$key]);
    }
}

// Assign the new order part
$collection->getSelect()->setPart('order', $order);
```

Once you're removed your unwanted order statement you can write the rest of your code:

```
$sortIds = array_map('intval', $productIds);
$collection->getSelect()
       ->order("find_in_set(e.entity_id,'".implode(',', $sortIds)."')");
```

NB: that is the general idea you may have to modify the foreach loop to match your needs.

Answer (score 0):

There's an extension to fix/work around this issue: https://github.com/Webtise/cat-index-position-fix