# Having trouble using catalog_product_list block to display a custom product collection

Tags: product, magento-enterprise, magento-1, magento-1.14

*Magento Enterprise v1.14.2*

I'd like to use the standard `catalog/product/list.phtml` template to display a custom set of products. In this case, I want to display the contents of the customer's wishlist and I'm editing `template/wishlist/shared.phtml`.

I get the product IDs from the customer's wishlist, create a product collection, create a product_list block, but the block just refuses to output only the products in my collection - instead, it outputs all products on the website.

```
<?php 
    if ($this->hasWishlistItems()) {

        // Get product IDs from wishlsit
        foreach ($this->getWishlistItems() as $item) {
            $productIds[] = $item->getProductId();
        }

        // Create collection of those products
        $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
                          ->getCollection()
                          ->addFieldToFilter("entity_id", array("in" => $productIds));

        // Create product_list block using the list.phtml template
        $block = Mage::getModel('core/layout')
                     ->createBlock('catalog/product_list')
                     ->setCollection($collection)
                     ->setTemplate('catalog/product/list.phtml');

        echo $block->toHtml(); // Showing ALL PRODUCTS on website!

    }
?>
```

I've tried using `setProductCollection()` and `setLoadedProductCollection()` but neither works, and I'm pretty sure `setCollection()` is the correct function anyway.

What's going on?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was a mostly unrelated fault. An SQL error was being generated by my collection's query string because of a Magento bug; the same issue faced in this question: ["random" order clause added to my collection](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/117711/random-order-clause-added-to-my-collection/174948#174948)

To fix it, I added a `setVisibility` line to the collection as per the above link.

I was also missing `addAttributeToSelect` which is unrelated.

My final code:

```
    $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
                  ->getCollection()
                  ->setVisibility(Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')->getVisibleInCatalogIds())
                  ->addAttributeToSelect("*")
                  ->addFieldToFilter("entity_id", array("in" => $productIds));

    $block = Mage::getModel('core/layout')
                 ->createBlock('catalog/product_list')
                 ->setTemplate('catalog/product/list.phtml')
                 ->setCollection($collection);

    return $block->toHtml();
```